# deadlock on too many requests and DoS occurred, Why?

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance, locking, deadlock

I ran into a strange monitoring DBA error "Deadlock" when I try to Pentest my web app. (Send lots of request to DB then Deadlock Occurred.)

Why did this occur?

[image]

I add the Deadlock XML Too:

[image]

I also add one XDL file too:

```
<deadlock>
  <victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="process18cbba9c8c8" />
  </victim-list>
  <process-list>
    <process id="process18cbba9c8c8" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 98:72057594046185472 (062d031fa481)" waittime="3289" ownerId="5036791424" transactionname="SELECT" lasttranstarted="2022-12-03T15:21:12.360" XDES="0x18655133ac0" lockMode="S" schedulerid="4" kpid="70452" status="suspended" spid="355" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2022-12-03T15:21:12.360" lastbatchcompleted="2022-12-03T15:21:12.360" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.360" clientapp="Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="......-deployment-867556c8d5-884hb" hostpid="1" loginname="......" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="5036791424" currentdb="98" currentdbname="......" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="78" stmtend="1420" sqlhandle="0x0200000004956a108160922a9b46f9e1be86fbc267c7f6c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
(@__request_PhoneNumber_0 nvarchar(11))SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[Email], [t].[FirstName], [t].[LastName], [t].[NationalCode], [t].[PhoneNumber], [i0].[Id], [i0].[CreatedAt], [i0].[CreatedBy], [i0].[Description], [i0].[InvestmentProjectId], [i0].[InvestorId], [i0].[IsSystemic], [i0].[ModifiedAt], [i0].[ModifiedBy], [i0].[Price], [i0].[RequestDate], [i0].[RequestStatus], [i0].[TrackingCode]
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(1) [i].[Id], [i].[Email], [i].[FirstName], [i].[LastName], [i].[NationalCode], [i].[PhoneNumber]
    FROM [Investment].[Investor] AS [i]
    WHERE [i].[PhoneNumber] = @__request_PhoneNumber_0
) AS [t]
LEFT JOIN [Investment].[InvestmentRequest] AS [i0] ON [t].[Id] = [i0].[InvestorId]
ORDER BY [t].[Id]   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process18ac127f848" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 98:72057594046185472 (062d031fa481)" waittime="3325" ownerId="5036791277" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2022-12-03T15:21:12.267" XDES="0x18c8d4d8420" lockMode="U" schedulerid="12" kpid="78800" status="suspended" spid="388" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2022-12-03T15:21:12.270" lastbatchcompleted="2022-12-03T15:21:12.263" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.263" clientapp="Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="......-deployment-867556c8d5-884hb" hostpid="1" loginname="......" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="5036791277" currentdb="98" currentdbname="......" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="adhoc" line="2" stmtstart="7352" stmtend="7972" sqlhandle="0x020000006e38cd07476eac92f82e6eef6044a90027a9ac8f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
(@p12 bigint,@p0 datetime2(7),@p1 bigint,@p2 nvarchar(1000),@p3 bigint,@p4 bigint,@p5 bit,@p6 datetime2(7),@p7 bigint,@p8 decimal(18,2),@p9 datetime2(7),@p10 int,@p11 nvarchar(4000),@p25 bigint,@p13 datetime2(7),@p14 bigint,@p15 nvarchar(1000),@p16 bigint,@p17 bigint,@p18 bit,@p19 datetime2(7),@p20 bigint,@p21 decimal(18,2),@p22 datetime2(7),@p23 int,@p24 nvarchar(4000),@p38 bigint,@p26 datetime2(7),@p27 bigint,@p28 nvarchar(1000),@p29 bigint,@p30 bigint,@p31 bit,@p32 datetime2(7),@p33 bigint,@p34 decimal(18,2),@p35 datetime2(7),@p36 int,@p37 nvarchar(4000),@p51 bigint,@p39 datetime2(7),@p40 bigint,@p41 nvarchar(1000),@p42 bigint,@p43 bigint,@p44 bit,@p45 datetime2(7),@p46 bigint,@p47 decimal(18,2),@p48 datetime2(7),@p49 int,@p50 nvarchar(4000),@p64 bigint,@p52 datetime2(7),@p53 bigint,@p54 nvarchar(1000),@p55 bigint,@p56 bigint,@p57 bit,@p58 datetime2(7),@p59 bigint,@p60 decimal(18,2),@p61 datetime2(7),@p62 int,@p63 nvarchar(4000),@p77 bigint,@p65 datetime2(7),@p66 bigint,@p67 nvarchar(1000),@p68 bigint,@p6   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process1865c3224e8" taskpriority="0" logused="2332" waitresource="KEY: 98:72057594042712064 (95272f5d4ae4)" waittime="3288" ownerId="5036790831" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2022-12-03T15:21:11.660" XDES="0x189f8c30420" lockMode="X" schedulerid="6" kpid="61288" status="suspended" spid="389" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2022-12-03T15:21:11.660" lastbatchcompleted="2022-12-03T15:21:11.660" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.660" clientapp="Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="......-deployment-867556c8d5-884hb" hostpid="1" loginname="......" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="5036790831" currentdb="98" currentdbname="......" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="adhoc" line="64" stmtstart="16710" stmtend="17022" sqlhandle="0x020000002001fa24cda173db057d08c461684176f5a396c90000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
(@p12 bigint,@p0 datetime2(7),@p1 bigint,@p2 nvarchar(1000),@p3 bigint,@p4 bigint,@p5 bit,@p6 datetime2(7),@p7 bigint,@p8 decimal(18,2),@p9 datetime2(7),@p10 int,@p11 nvarchar(4000),@p25 bigint,@p13 datetime2(7),@p14 bigint,@p15 nvarchar(1000),@p16 bigint,@p17 bigint,@p18 bit,@p19 datetime2(7),@p20 bigint,@p21 decimal(18,2),@p22 datetime2(7),@p23 int,@p24 nvarchar(4000),@p38 bigint,@p26 datetime2(7),@p27 bigint,@p28 nvarchar(1000),@p29 bigint,@p30 bigint,@p31 bit,@p32 datetime2(7),@p33 bigint,@p34 decimal(18,2),@p35 datetime2(7),@p36 int,@p37 nvarchar(4000),@p51 bigint,@p39 datetime2(7),@p40 bigint,@p41 nvarchar(1000),@p42 bigint,@p43 bigint,@p44 bit,@p45 datetime2(7),@p46 bigint,@p47 decimal(18,2),@p48 datetime2(7),@p49 int,@p50 nvarchar(4000),@p64 bigint,@p52 datetime2(7),@p53 bigint,@p54 nvarchar(1000),@p55 bigint,@p56 bigint,@p57 bit,@p58 datetime2(7),@p59 bigint,@p60 decimal(18,2),@p61 datetime2(7),@p62 int,@p63 nvarchar(4000),@p77 bigint,@p65 datetime2(7),@p66 bigint,@p67 nvarchar(1000),@p68 bigint,@p6   </inputbuf>
    </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
    <keylock hobtid="72057594046185472" dbid="98" objectname=".......Investment.InvestmentRequest" indexname="PK_InvestmentRequest" id="lock189cdffa680" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594046185472">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process18ac127f848" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process18cbba9c8c8" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
    <keylock hobtid="72057594046185472" dbid="98" objectname=".......Investment.InvestmentRequest" indexname="PK_InvestmentRequest" id="lock189cdffa680" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594046185472">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process1865c3224e8" mode="X" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process18ac127f848" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
    <keylock hobtid="72057594042712064" dbid="98" objectname=".......Investment.Investor" indexname="PK_Investor" id="lock18a5cc15380" mode="S" associatedObjectId="72057594042712064">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process18cbba9c8c8" mode="S" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process1865c3224e8" mode="X" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
  </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Comment: The screen image is missing important details to help troubleshoot. Add the deadlock XML graph to your question (obfuscated as desired). Generally, deadlocks are due to the need for query/index tuning, restrictive transaction isolation levels, or app design. If your deadlocks do not occur under app normal usage, be aware load/stress tests can cause them due to more concurrent queries and timing.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help @DanGuzman you are so nice person which help others. I add deadlock XML Too. would you please help me more? thanks so much.

Comment: Add the deadlock XML text (from the xdl file) to your question. Screen images make it more difficult for us to help you and may be the reason for the downvotes too.

Comment: @DanGuzman I also add XML from XDL file. thanks so much.

Comment: Does your pentest modify `Investment.InvestmentRequest` rows for the same `InvestorId` using multiple threads? I don't know your application but that doesn't seem like a scenario that would occur in a real workload and is prone to deadlocks, especially with concurrent `SELECT` queries for the same `InvestorId`.